# Jersey;: Registering Injected ExceptionMapper Instances via SpringServlet

Tags: spring, jersey

Jersey: 1.12
Spring: 3.11
JDK: 1.6.0_35
Tomcat: 6..0.33

I am trying to register ExceptionMapper instances for a Jersey servlet that are instantiated by a Spring IoC container in the context of a SpringServlet, and am running into ye olde "The scope of the component class X must be a singleton" exception during the Jersey servlet initialization. I'm not in a position to post the actual code at this time, so I'm going to give the essentials of the implementation to see if something obvious jumps out at someone, or if I can be pointed at some documentation that I have missed.

The ExceptionMapper instance is essentially as follows:

```
// ... package definitions omitted ...

@Provider
@Singleton
public class MyExceptionMapper
    implements ExceptionMapper<MyException>
{
    // ... injected attributes omitted ...

    @Override
    public Response toResponse(MyException exception)
    {
        // ... specific handling logic omitted ...

       return Response.status(Status.BAD_REQUEST).entity(exception.getMessage()).build();
    }
}
```

The bean definition in applicationContext.xml is as follows, which defaults to singleton scope (and adding an explicit scope specifier doesn't seem to change the behavior):

```
<bean id="myExceptionMapper" class="my.package.MyExceptionMapper" />
```

The Spring context loader listener and SpringServlet configuration in web.xml are essentially boilerplate, and the servlet will load, initialize and operate properly with other inject attributes when the bean definition for MyExceptionMapper is commented out of the applicationContext.xml. But when the bean definition is present in applicationContext.xml, I get log messages to the effect of:

```
SpringProviderFactory - Registering Spring bean, myExpectionMapper, of type my.package.MyExceptionMapper as a provider class
SpringProviderFactory - Registering Spring bean, myServiceController, of type my.package.MyServiceController as a root resource class
... other root resource classes loading ...
SpringServlet - Exception occurred when initialization
java.lang.RuntimeException: The scope of the component class my.package.MyExceptionMapper must be a singleton
  at som.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ioc.IoCProviderFactory.wrap(...)
```

I have tried placing MyExceptionMapper in the scanned packages hierarchy to be picked up by the SpringServlet during initialization, and in a separate package hierarchy, and the results do not change.

Any assistance or guidance on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you double-checked that you are using javax.inject.Singleton and the javax.inject annotations are enabled in Spring?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stepped on same problem with Spring 3.2.3 and Jersey 2.3.1 integration.

What worked for me was combination of two:

1. Annotating jersey `@Provider` class with `@Service` or making it explicitly singleton in app-context xml

   ```
   @Service //implies a singleton-scope
   @Provider
   public class UnhandledExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<Throwable> {

       @Override
       public Response toResponse(Throwable exception) { //...
   ```
2. Adding package that contains provider class to jersey packages, I prefer to do this in MyApplication class:

   ```
   public class MyApplication extends ResourceConfig {
   public MyApplication() {
       packages("com.mycompany.api.controller", "com.mycompany.api.jersey");
               //....
       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 4):

My `ExceptionMapper`s are under the structure where I'm doing component scan, and mine are simply annotated with `@Component` for Spring registry and `@Provider` for Jersey.

My component scan just looks like:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.company.web"/>
```

and the `ExceptionMapper` looks pretty much like yours:

```
package com.mycompany.web.provider;

import com.mycompany.exception.SpecialException;
import com.mycompany.exception.Error;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.ExceptionMapper;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;

@Provider
@Component
public class SpecialExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<SpecialException> {

    @Autowired
    private MessageSource messageSource;

    @Override
    public Response toResponse(SpecialException exception) {

        Error error = new Error();


        error.errorMessage = messageSource.getMessage(exception.getResourceBundleKey(), exception.getArgs());

        return Response.status(Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST).
                entity(error).
                type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).
                build();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Adding the scope explicitly in the spring config did the trick for me:

```
<bean id="exceptionMapper" class="my.pkg.MyExceptionMapper" scope="singleton" />
```

Comment: Okay, it did the trick, but what does this mean ? Doesn't Spring consider all the beans defined in the XML as singleton by default ? Why do we need to explicitly specify this ?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, but with a MessageReaderWriterProvider class:

```
package my.provider.package;
...
@Provider
@Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, "text/json"})
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, "text/json"})
public class ReRwProvider extends AbstractMessageReaderWriterProvider<Object> {
...
}
```

The solution was to add the package of this class in an init-param tag for Jersey's SpringServlet in web.xml:

```
<init-param>
    <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
    <param-value>my.provider.package</param-value>
</init-param>
```

Note that you should not define this bean in your Spring context.

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me that the ExceptionMapper has to be configured as a "singleton" with Spring. If you want to use the annotation configuration you have to pay attentions because jersey has a "@Singleton" annotation too (with a different meaning of the javax.inject.Singleton interpreted by spring)
To avoid any confusion I prefer use the spring @Service annotation, that implies a singleton scope... so:

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.ExceptionMapper;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;

@Service //implies a singleton-scope
@Provider
public class UnhandledExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<Throwable> {

    @Override
    public Response toResponse(Throwable exception) {
        return Response.status(Response.Status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
                .entity(new ErrorBean(false, exception.getMessage(), null))
                .build();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I also found sometime coustom ExceptionMapper not work, and it's not always work or not work.

so i debug the jersey's source code .

class: org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime, methed:mapException

```
 ...
 final long timestamp = tracingLogger.timestamp(ServerTraceEvent.EXCEPTION_MAPPING);
 **ExceptionMapper mapper = runtime.exceptionMappers.findMapping(throwable);**
 if (mapper != null) {
      request.getRequestEventBuilder().setExceptionMapper(mapper);
```

...
if the mapper is null, the coustom ExceptionMapper will be not work.

class: org.glassfish.jersey.internal.ExceptionMapperFactory methed: ExceptionMapperFactory

the Exception Mapper :(there two Exception mapping one same Exception: java.lang.Exception)

org.glassfish.jersey.server.mvc.internal.ErrorTemplateExceptionMapper@6473fc2,class java.lang.Exception

...

com.baidu.ssp.web.ws.exception.BaseExceptionMapper@7a84639c,class java.lang.Exception

it's because in MvcFeature:

@Override
public boolean configure(final FeatureContext context) {
    final Configuration config = context.getConfiguration();

```
if (!config.isRegistered(ErrorTemplateExceptionMapper.class)) {
    context.register(ErrorTemplateExceptionMapper.class);
    context.register(new MvcBinder());

    return true;
}

return false;
```

}
the ErrorTemplateExceptionMapper is also add to ExceptionMapper.

so i change my custom MapperException's genericity type : ExceptionMapper to ExceptionMapper

may be my resolution is not fit for you , the main problem is the ExceptionMapper